# HTML5 canvas line into a zig zag line?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a line between 2 points. The line can be at any angle.

Ex

```js
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const from = {x:50, y:50};
const to = {x: 100, y: 125};
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

How can I turn it into a zig zag line?

**Edit**
So Im making in small basketball coaching app. Where you should be able to draw lines to show how an exercise should be performed. You draw a straight line and then you can with menu buttons change that line to become dashed and / or zig zagged.

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Line {
    constructor(fromPoint = null, toPoint = null) {
        this.from = fromPoint;
        this.to = toPoint;
        this.dashed = false;
        this.zigZagged = false;
    }

    setFrom(point) { this.from = point;}

    setTo(point) { this.to = toPoint;}

    getFrom() { return this.from; }

    getTo() { return this.to}

    draw(ctx, color = '#000', lineWidth = 2.0) {
        ctx.beginPath();

        if (this.dashed) {
            ctx.setLineDash([5, 10]);
        } else {
            ctx.setLineDash([]);
        }

        //Starting point of the line
        ctx.moveTo(this.from.x, this.from.y);

        if (this.zigZagged) {
            // Need help with this function
            this.drawZigZagged();
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(this.to.x, this.to.y);
        }



        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    drawZigZagged(ctx) {
        // PLEASE help creating this function
        // .. help
        // .. use this.from and this.to to create a zig zag line
        // .. maybe something like 20px for each individual zig zag line
        // .. I guess the function have to calculate the angle the
        // .. current line have (this.from - this.to)
        // .. to be able to create a zig zag line instead of a straight line
    }

    setDashed(enable) {
        this.dashed = enable;
    }

    setZigZagged(enable){
        this.zigZagged = enable
    }
}
```

So please help me create the drawZigZagged(ctx) {...} function

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is pretty broad--there are a lot of zigzag lines possible. What should it look like? What parameters do you need for controlling the kind of zigging or zagging?

Comment: Please add an example output for us.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for you comment. I have updated my question but I just noticed that it did not answer your question. Regarding the look and feel of the zig zag line. I would like to have maybe 20px. So for a completely straight horizontal line it would be 20px going 45 degrees down -  then 20px 45 degrees up - then 20px 45 degrees down - etc etc until you reach the end point (this.to in the above example). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ggorlen is it possible to remove this question from "hold" status?

Comment: Sure. If you edit your question with an image showing exactly what kind of zig zag you're trying to draw and make an attempt at doing so in `drawZigZagged(ctx) {`, it'll show up in the "re-open" queue and people will vote on re-opening it (I'd be happy to do so, but as it stands, it's still pretty broad, see my earlier comment).

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to do it. So here is my code for making a line zig zagged. See prepareZigZag and drawZigZag. I have commented the so it should be pretty straight forward to understand whats happening. Hope it can help someone. Please comment improvements.

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Line {
    constructor(fromPoint = null, toPoint = null, zigZagged = false) {
        this.from = fromPoint;
        this.to = toPoint;
        this.dashed = false;
        this.zigZagged = zigZagged;

        this.prepareZigZag();
    }

    setFrom(point) { this.from = point;}

    setTo(point) { this.to = toPoint;}

    getFrom() { return this.from; }

    getTo() { return this.to}

    prepareZigZag() {
        // Get the radian angle of the line
        this.lineRadians = Math.atan2(this.to.y - this.from.y, this.to.x - this.from.x);

        // Get the length of the line
        const a = this.from.x - this.to.x;
        const b = this.from.y - this.to.y;
        this.lineLength = Math.sqrt( a * a + b * b );

        // 10 pixels between each zig zag "wave"
        this.zigzagSpacing = 10;

        // Length of one zig zag line - will in reality be doubled see below usage
        this.oneZigZagLength = 10;

        //Length of the last straight bit - so we do not zig zag all the line
        this.straightLengthWhenZigZag = 30

        // The length of the zig zag lines
        this.zigZagLength = this.lineLength - this.straightLengthWhenZigZag;
    }


    draw(ctx, color = '#000', lineWidth = 2.0) {
        if (this.dashed) {
            ctx.setLineDash([4, 2]);
        } else {
            ctx.setLineDash([]);
        }

        if (this.zigZagged) {
            this.drawZigZagged(ctx);
        } else {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(this.from.x, this.from.y);
            ctx.lineTo(this.to.x, this.to.y);
        }
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.stroke();

    }

    drawZigZagged(ctx) {
        // Save the current drawing state
        ctx.save();

        // Begin the new path
        ctx.beginPath();

        //Set the new 0, 0
        ctx.translate(this.from.x, this.from.y);

        // Rotate the canvas so we can treat it like straight
        ctx.rotate(this.lineRadians);

        // Begin from 0, 0 (ie this.from.x, this.from.y)
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        let zx = 0;
        // Create zig zag lines
        for (let n = 0; zx < this.zigZagLength; n++) {
            // The new zig zag x position
            zx = ((n + 1) * this.zigzagSpacing);

            // The new zig zag y position - each and other time up and down
            const  zy = (n % 2 == 0) ? -this.oneZigZagLength : this.oneZigZagLength;

            // Draw the an actual line of the zig zag line
            ctx.lineTo(zx, zy);
        }
        // Back to the center vertically
        ctx.lineTo(this.lineLength - (this.straightLengthWhenZigZag / 2), 0);

        // Draw the last bit straight
        ctx.lineTo(this.lineLength, 0);

        // Restore the previous drawing state
        ctx.restore();
    }

    setDashed(enable) {
        this.dashed = enable;
    }

    setZigZagged(enable){
        this.zigZagged = enable
    }
}
```